# Qt binary reading error in qDatastream

Tags: c++, qt, binary, precision

I am reading a binary file that is a produced by a sensor. I am having problem in reading float with different precision (32 or 64). I can read them in MATLAB (64 bit version) but Qt (32 bit version on windows) is giving wrong values. I can read till `dtmth` (please ref structure below) . After it I am getting a value `Inf` for `baseline`. This value is `0` in fact. As you can see, I changed MSB (LittleEndian). If I keep BigEndian, I get `0` for baseline but others values are wrong then. My desktop is 64 bit.

I have checked number of bytes and they are correct. I think the problem is machine precision.

```
QDataStream in(&file);

           in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
           params p;

           in >> p.filetype;               
           in >> p.projectid;
           in >> p.datamin;               
           in >> p.dtyear;
           in >> p.dtmth;              
           in >> p.baseline;
           in >> p.startfrequ;
```

Where p is a structure defined as:

```
    struct params
    {
        quint8 filetype;   
        quint16 projectid;
        double datamin;
        quint16 dtyear;
        quint8 dtmth;    
        float baseline;
        double startfrequ;

    };
```

I can read them in MATLAB. My matlab is 64 bit version where I read data types as following:

```
MATLAB:
        uint8 filetype;   
        uint16 projectid;
        float64 datamin;
        uint16 dtyear;
        uint8 dtmth;    
        float32 baseline;
        float64 startfrequ;
```

Let me know if I missed any details.

EDIT:

Reading file:

```
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), QString(),
               tr("Raw Files (*.msr);;All files (*.*)"));

           if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
               qDebug("Attempting to open file..");
               QFile file(fileName);
               if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                   QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not open file"));
                   return;
               }

               QDataStream in(&file);
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you also read correctly `datamin`??

Comment: Hi again @UmNyobe . That is where I am confused. I am reading right number of bytes, and both values are 0. so I am not sure if they are correct or not. But then I am reading dtyear correctly. Further, value of baseline is also 0, which I am getting as Inf.

Comment: Is `file` opened in binary mode? On Windows, you have to differentiate binary and text mode; text mode changes `0x13 0x10` pairs into just `0x10` on input, so it could corrupt your data.

Comment: I am using QFile which by default assumes binary. (question updated)

Comment: did you tried switching precision each time??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Qt are you using? If the version is  superior to Qt 4.6, then the default precision is 64 bit, [which means Qt will try to read your float 32 as a float 64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#setFloatingPointPrecision). You need to manually set the precision with `in.setFloatingPointPrecision ( QDataStream::SinglePrecision);`

```
       in >> p.filetype;               
       in >> p.projectid;
       in >> p.datamin;               
       in >> p.dtyear;
       in >> p.dtmth;    
       in.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
       in >> p.baseline;
       in.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::DoublePrecision);
       in >> p.startfrequ;
```

From your comment it seems this was the issue. Indeed, if you set to single precision, and you try to read `p.datamin` or `p.startfrequ` (64 bits), then the data stream will read them as 32 bits floats. and not only  `p.datamin` will be incorrect but all values after it.

For a start, to check that my suggestion worked use after the last line

```
      if(in.status() == QDataStream::ReadCorruptData){
            qDebug() << "still doesnt work";
      }
```

Comment: My Qt is 5.0.1 (32 bit). 
I already tried that before posting this question. But then all values are wrong after projectid. Though datamin is 0.

Comment: Naresh, it confirms that this is your issue. I never tried it, but use the sample code in my edit and tell me if it's correct. I believe this is insane from the qt guys.

Comment: hi @UmNyobe . I actually thought of it. But I assumed Qt wont be that stupid. But it actually is. It fixed the problem. I actually had a lot more of header information than I put here so I had to change 3 times and then I read right values. Is there a fix? Write own function that changes precision for floats and doubles?

Comment: The only reason which come to my mind is that QDataStream is designed to write and read a platform-independent byte stream for serialising objects. Still it sucks, because you basically need to write what you say, a custom wrapper.